# Extend windows server 2008r2 default 100 mb system partition?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, partition

I need to extend my 100 mb system partition, but cannot figure out how to do so! I cannot do it in disk management because the c:\ partition is "in the way", ment as when I resize c:\ partition, any unallocated partition will be placed to the right of this and not to the left, so system partition is not "extendable".

Am I missing something?

Can I "merge" this system partition with the c:\ partition, so bootmgr is still to be used?

Comment: Why do you NEED to extend that? This one is not meant to be even played around with by you. I would rather say you need to read documentation about what the system partition is. Please explain.

Comment: @TomTom: I certainly agree with you, but I have an error which leeds me into thinking that this should be a way out. Please see my comment to JamesRyan! And also I'm a developer not an administrator, so my knowledge is lacking on this...

Comment: Well it seems MS advice with mdt2010 is to use mdt2012 or resize that partion to 300Mb as a stopgap.  Doesn't sound like great advice, it's liable to break something else down the line, but easily done using a gparted bootdisc.

Comment: Well, I reinstalled server2008r2 on my base server with partioning the hole c:\ drive as a system drive, so now I have got space enough for winpe. And also taking the image wasn't a problem nomore! Thanks for all your answers and comments.

Comment: @JamesRyan: Where did you look up this MS advice...?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/mdt/thread/3505709e-b924-4dfc-b1ba-196956031bb6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution that doesn't require a (hazardous) repartitioning would be to make the C drive the active partition.  Of course, you'll need to use system repair (or some other means) to install the boot loader on the C drive or the system won't be bootable!

It is likely that MDT will then correctly identify the C drive as the active partition and put WinPE there.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you don't need to resize that partion.  Whatever you are planning to put on there is almost certainly better off on c:\ or another partition.  Don't assign it a drive letter and leave it alone.

Comment: Basically you are right, but the setup is a little bit more complicated than that! I'm trying to take an image of a baseserver (2008r2) with mdt2010/waik. MDT resides on a 2008r2 deployserver (which is now virtual). When I run LiteTouch.vbs on the baseserver (from the deployserver share) I get an error saying it failed to apply Windows PE, there is not enough space on the disk! I'm not really sure, but I think it's trying to apply wpe to the system partition. I have'nt had any errors in the past when mdt resided on my laptop...

Answer (score 1):

This site is great, when you typed in the title of your question it listed a bunch of previously asked questions matching the keywords in your title. Many if not all of these suggested previous questions answered your question without you having to type another word, so would a simple search. This site's here to create questions and answers that people can use for long periods of time, so if people don't use this mechanism they're not adding anything at all, so in future can you allow the site to lead you by the hand as it does to existing answers please.

Either way you want [gpartd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

That partition is created for the use of Bitlocker, should you choose to use it, and isn't something you should mess with.